# IE8 bug: Am I missing something in the CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, transition

I've customized the CSS transitions on the [Media Grid plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/media-grid-wordpress-responsive-portfolio/2218545?ref=LCweb&ref=LCweb&clickthrough_id=177967635&redirect_back=true) and they're working everywhere except IE8. That's fine. I can live without the transitions but I still need the div containing the individuals name and title to appear. Right now they don't show up at all. I've tried everything I can think of but I can't find the answer. Could someone point me in the right direction?

http://clients.weinsteinau.cgvcreative.com/team/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IE8 I'm afraid you will have to make a separate stylesheet and start from your class .overlays than dig deeper into those divs, you will have to change positioning, height and width. There are a few elements without dimensions and IE8 does not like that. Let me know how it goes, and oh yeah good luck! :)

Comment: I haven't had the chance to work on it much but doing some inital work in IE8 dev tools looks good. Thanks!